# Selecting Pareto-Dominant Vector

Tags: python, optimization

I want to compare two vector. This vector represents two alternative:

```
def select_dominant(a,b):
    comp=a>b
    if(comp):
        return a
    elif(a<b):
        return b
    else:
        return "indifferent"

a=[1,10,1]
b=[1,1,10]
print(select_dominant(a,b))
```

It's expected that a and b should be "indifferent" because a and b can't **dominate** each other. For values like a=[1,1,1] b=[1,1,2] there is no problem for this code because b dominated to a.
Consequently, i want to get "indifferent" return from this function. How can i get?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want to compare two lists *elementwise*. If *all*
the values in `a` are greater than or equal to the corresponding values in `b`, then
return `a`, if less than or equal return `b`, and otherwise return `'indifferent'`.

You can apply the `>=` operator to each element of `a` and `b` like this:

```
In [247]: a = [1,10,1]

In [248]: b = [1,1,10]

In [249]: map(operator.ge, a, b)
Out[249]: [True, True, False]
```

And you can test if all the values are `True` using `all`:

```
In [250]: all(map(operator.ge, a, b))
Out[250]: False
```

Thus, if you define:

```
import operator
def select_dominant(a,b):
    ge = all(map(operator.ge, a, b))
    le = all(map(operator.le, a, b))
    return a if ge else b if le else 'indifferent'
```

then

```
In [242]: select_dominant([1,1,1], [1,1,2])
Out[242]: [1, 1, 2]

In [243]: select_dominant([1,1,2], [1,1,1])
Out[243]: [1, 1, 2]

In [244]: select_dominant([1,10,1], [1,1,10])
Out[244]: 'indifferent'
```

---

The expression

```
a if ge else b if le else 'indifferent'
```

is a so-called [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).
It is a short-hand way to generate the same value that this code would assign to `value`:

```
if ge:
    value = a
elif le:
    value = b
else:
    value = 'indifferent'
```

Comment: Depending on application you might need a case for lists being equal.

Comment: @unutbu, is this the fastest way to compare dominance between two vectors?

Comment: I can't tell you what is fastest but in some cases using NumPy's `np.greater_equal` might be faster -- especially if the data is already in a NumPy array, the arrays are large, or if you can arrange the data in such a way as to call `np.greater_equal` *once* on big arrays instead of calling `map(operator.ge, a, b)` multiple times. So the answer depends a lot on the details of your particular problem.