# Pick up an item with a dominant vector from a priority queue

Tags: python, queue, priority-queue

To implement `A*`the [priority queue](https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/implementation.html#python-dijkstra)

```
import heapq
class PriorityQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = []

    def empty(self):
        return len(self.elements) == 0

    def put(self, item, priority):
        heapq.heappush(self.elements, (priority, item))

    def get(self):
        return heapq.heappop(self.elements)[1]
```

can be used. When an `item` is picked up, the `priority` number is the smallest among the priority numbers of the remaining items in the queue. In the `NAMOA` [algorithm](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/1754399.1754400), instead of a single number that defines the priority, a vector is used. Thus, when an `item` is picked up, the associated vector is "dominant".

> The vector `f` dominates the vector `f'` if  [image].

For example, the vector `(2, 3)` dominates `(2, 4)`, but no dominance relation exists for `(2, 3)` and `(3, 2)`. To decide if a vector is dominant we can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27880627/selecting-pareto-dominant-vector). So far I have tried

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, item: int, vec: list):
        self.item = item
        self.vec = vec

    def __lt__(self, obj):
        """self.vec < obj.vec"""
        return map(operator.lt, self.vec, obj.vec)

    def __le__(self, obj):
        """self <= obj."""
        return map(operator.le, self.vec, obj.vec)

    def __eq__(self, obj):
        """self == obj."""
        return map(operator.eq, self.vec, obj.vec)

    def __ne__(self, obj):
        """self != obj."""
        return map(operator.ne, self.vec, obj.vec)

    def __gt__(self, obj):
        """self > obj."""
        return map(operator.gt, self.vec, obj.vec)

    def __ge__(self, obj):
        """self >= obj."""
        return map(operator.ge, self.vec, obj.vec)

class PriorityQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = []

    def empty(self):
        return len(self.elements) == 0

    def push(self, node):
        heapq.heappush(self.elements, node)

    def pop(self):
        x = heapq.heappop(self.elements)
        return x.item

# Example
open = PriorityQueue()
open.push(Node('source1', [2, 3]))
open.push(Node('source2', [1, 1]))
open.push(Node('source3', [2, 4]))
item = open.pop()
```

The picked up item is `source3`, while the desired result is `source2`, with the dominant vector, i.e., `[1, 1]`.

Could you please someone cast some light?

Comment: I think I go it, `all` is needed around `map`. I will tested a little more. Any comments are highly appreciated.